# Mover imágenes sobre un mapa y guardar ubicación en MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

¿Alguien me puede recomendar sobre algún curso o tutorial que me enseñe a crear una página que me permita tomar un elemento (imagen pequeña), ubicarlo en un mapa y que su posición quede guardada?.

Esto para que cualquier otra persona que visualiza el sitio web pueda ver la imagen en la última posición guardada.

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una web con JS y PHP, con base de datos MySQL y esta parte quiero agregarla en una de las páginas de mi sitio web.

De antemano, agradezco su respuesta.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Recomienden una librería/herramienta para..." no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre opinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu recomendación, como plantearías la duda que expongo en mi post?

Comment: Dos caminos. 1) Reducir la pregunta a un problema concreto. Ver cómo vas a guardar las coordenadas que necesitas usar para cuando "cualquier otra persona" vea el sitio y se cargue el mapa en esas coordenadas. Elegir qué API de mapas vas a usar. Hacer una prueba de concepto con eso. Traerla junto con una dificultad concreta al implementar eso. 2) Ir al [chat] (creo que te hacen falta puntos de rep)